# Attach a handler for all event types

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a neat way to bind an event handler to an element irrespective of event type?

For e.g., I need something like:

```
$('#elem').bind(function(e){

    //do stuff for any event originating from this element
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This question have a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/how-all-events-of-dom-element-can-be-bind

Comment: Thanks, somehow that didn't show up in the 'similar questions' sections when I was posting this. :)   Anyways, my question says 'neat' I would still like to know if there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default behavior of `bind` method.
If we give a one argument which will function add this to all events
Check this out.

```
$.fn.init.prototype.bind  = ( function( old ) {  

     return function( ) { 
        if( arguments.length == 1 && typeof arguments[0] === "function" ) { 
          // if we'll put to bind method one argument which is function 

          // list of whole of events - you set themselves as needed
          return this.bind( "click keydown keyup keypress mouseover mouseenter  mouseout mouseleave mousedown mouseup mousemove change blur focus scroll resize load unload beforeunload", arguments[0] );

        } else { 
            // trigger original bind method
            return old.apply( this, arguments ) 
        } ;
     }  

})( $.fn.init.prototype.bind );
```

and now:

```
$( "body" ).bind( function() { console.log( this ) } );
```

Poof :)

Comment: you looks rockstar in plugin developers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var eventsList = "blur, focus, load, resize, 
                scroll, unload, beforeunload, click, dblclick, 
                mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, 
                mouseenter, mouseleave, change, select, submit, keydown, 
                keypress, keyup, error";

(/*  selector of user choice   */).bind(eventsList, function(){

//All operations here..
});
```

You can find list of events here... [JQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)