# Catch all events in iframe jQuery and replicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

This is the question:

I have an iframe that displays any web page (not necessarily developed by me).
On this page may be attached events (which presumably I do not know).

How can I dynamically intercepting these events and store them for later replicate?

For example:
suppose that when the mouse moves over a certain div it changes color.
I would like to make sure that when you trigger the event that would change color to the div it is "registered" with all a series of information that will allow me (without user interaction) to replicate it at a later time.

Ideas for both the recording and subsequent replication?

Comment: If the iframed page is not on the same domain, this needs to be prevented by the browser for security reasons.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for an automated test framework?

Comment: not really, the idea is to synchronize the UI in a site;

Comment: Did you find any reasonable answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: **you cannot**.

You cannot access the document object of "any web page" with JavaScript on your page if it is on a different domain, which I assume if you say "any web page", because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You would need the website in the IFRAME to cooperate with your script to achieve this, which will not happen with "any web page".

**IFRAME on same domain**
If your web page is on the same domain then you can access the events of the IFRAMEs body element by adding a listener for every event you want to catch like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/jquery-how-can-i-bind-all-events-on-a-dom-element). This is possible for all events that [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to the body. So if you have Events that are prevented from bubbling upwards to the body, they will not be catched with this solution.

```
jQuery('#website body').on('click mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

Assuming you have an IFRAME with the id `website` you can catch the events you wish by listing them separated with spaces as above. The example catches `click`, `mousover` and `mouseout`.

Maybe this is closer to what you want?

Comment: Okay, so let's say I do this on the same domain. I overcome the Same Origin Policy via a proxy, but it is not of interest in this topic.

What I'm interested in is how you can do this: how can I intercept events fired by a page, record them and play them back at a later time.

Thanks anyway for the quick response

Comment: yes, thanks,

I had read such a solution in another post, but that would add a listener for each event that I added to every element on the page, right?

More specifically I was looking for something that would make me recognize the events already on the page and intercept.

browsing I found something like $("#element").data("events");

but I cannot find online documentation or specific examples of how to use it :(

Comment: With the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) you can store data to a DOM element. I doubt it will be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handlers to your divs. For your example you could use

```
$('#div').mouseover(function(e) { ... })
```

or

```
('#div').on('mouseover', function(e) { ... })
```

For 'replication', you'd have to store information about past events in some object. You could even store the event object itself.

Comment: This solution assumes that I know the elements of the page, and the events are attached to them;
I look for a generic solution, an "allEventListener"