# how can a user identify any events

Tags: jquery, events

With so many different devices, doing so many different things I thought it might be useful to create a universal listener. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cneeds/p5kcx6c3/) is my simple attempt that, of course, cannot work. But it may just stimulate someone into coming up with a real solution:-

```
$("#allEvents").on("*", function(evnt) {
    console.log(evnt.type);
});

<div id="allEvents">
    this is some text inside div allEvents
</div>
```

Alternatively, is there something out there that can tell a user what events are fired when they do certain things on their devices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I bind all events on a DOM element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/how-can-i-bind-all-events-on-a-dom-element)

Comment: I'm looking at that @Antony but so far I can't get it to work. I'm obviously missing something critical

Answer (score 0):

The nearest you can get is to get all the events that a browser supports and put it in a array and then bind to it and check the `event.type`. For that we will use `Object.keys` to get the keys of `document` and then we will filter off to only include events and remove the "on" prefix from them.

Now, we have got an array of events supported by the browser without "on" prefix which we can join with `Array.join(" ")` and then we can make use of `e` to check against the type of event.

```
var arr = Object.keys(document).filter(function(x) {
    return x.indexOf("on") == 0
}).map(function(x) {
    return x.replace("on", "");
});
$('#allEvents').on(arr.join(" "), function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Comment: This then assumes that I know what events each (and every) browser supports? I was hoping to come from the POV that I don't know, how can I find out (aside from reading the documentation for every browser and every platform that it supports)?

Comment: @cneeds ah! My code will work nearly in every browser as the events are nearly same.

Comment: Until you start including tabs, notes, i-phones, etc. @Amit

Comment: @cneeds hey! javascript is javascript everywhere.. I'm just taking the events which is present in the browser that's executing it so how do you suppose the code will break?

Comment: No @Amit, that's not what I'm saying. I tried your code in the fiddle and I can't get it to work...

Comment: My code = Take the event from browser. I'm not assuming that you know. `Object.keys(document).filter(function(x) {
    return x.indexOf("on") == 0
}).map(function(x) {
    return x.replace("on", "");
});` is the code to get the events from the browser.

Comment: OK, I see that now, but it's not working:- http://jsfiddle.net/cneeds/p5kcx6c3/1/