# Javascript - Ignore 3rd party libraries when debugging?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

**Is there anyway to ignore 3rd party javascript when debugging?**

I use *lots* of 3rd party libraries in my javascript code, and would like to completely ignore them when debugging. Why? Because I'd prefer to assume that they work as intended, and stepping into their code (or having to navigate the call stack for their functions) isn't necessary 99% of the time - most of the time the code I want to debug is my own code - not theirs!

I specifically am using Chrome most of the time when debugging, but am totally willing to switch to something else if this capability was available!

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126822/can-i-tell-the-chrome-script-debugger-to-ignore-jquery-js

Comment: Check out this post (5th or 6th answer down): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096581/how-do-i-skip-or-ignore-errors-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @machineghost - thanks! that totally looks like the answer - you should submit that as an answer here before it gets closed.

Comment: I didn't provide an answer because this question is really a duplicate of that one, and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment made by @machineghost, [led me to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827882/avoid-stepping-through-javascript-file-in-chrome-developer-tools/21016567#21016567) on StackOverflow, which details how to do this in Chrome: