# Run javascript on a page in slow motion?

Tags: javascript

I need to use my developer tools to inspect an element on the pages' CSS. My issue is that the element only appears for a brief moment and is then hidden again with javascript.

Is there a way (maybe with a browser add on or with the developer tools) so slow down javascript on a page? So when I click the trigger element that reveals the element I need to style it will appear on the screen for a bit longer?

Comment: Just edit your Js code so that the element isnt hidden. Inspect it, do whate ever you want and then get back to your original code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Debugging line by line using Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638059/javascript-debugging-line-by-line-using-google-chrome)

Comment: [Here's a video of how to debug javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htZAU7FM7GI).

Comment: I would also like to know if this is possible ... I want to automatically "step" every x seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add breakpoints in Chrome Devtools

[image]

On the bottom right you can see your local variables in their current state.

[image]

You can step through your javascript code by pressing F11

Comment: While this may be a good answer to the OP's problem, it does not actually explain how to execute code in slow motion.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of process is doing the CSS change? If it's javascript, you could set a breakpoint and step through the process.

Answer (score 0):

In the developer tools of your browser you can issue Javascipt commands on the command line. For example, if you want to show a hidden element you could use a command like

```
document.getElementById('element').style.display = '';
```

And then to hide it again you could use

```
document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none';
```

If you're using a framework there are many short-cuts to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Show animations" drawer in developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+P and search for "Show animations [Drawer]"). Click animation speed to 10% and you can even click one of the saved animations (grey boxes) and get a timeline slider that allows going backwards and forwards in the animation. This obviously only works for declarative animations and if JavaScript is used to emulate animations, you have to step through the code.

If you need to interrupt the JavaScript code, try setting some breakpoints, either manually or automatically. For example, you can use Sources – Event Listener Breakpoints and select e.g. following:

- Animation
- Canvas
- DOM Mutation
- Media
- Timer

You can probably only select Animation and Timer, and that should be plenty to step through the animation frame by frame. Simply press F8 if you want to continue to next frame (breakpoint).

For further details, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/animations