# How can i insert objects into a HTML table using JavaScript / AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a site that takes information form a music forum by searching an artist name and populates the artist 5 top albums, by popularity, number of tracks and release date. The information is pulling correctly from the site but when I go to create and HTML table no information is displayed. Search button is function properly, its calling all the right information, can help provide a solution in which I can extract the information from the array and populate/ create a table in HTML? below is the code I am currently working with.

```js
function searchClicked() {
   var artist_name = document.getElementById("artistName").value;

   var data = {};
   data.ArtistName = artist_name
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/SearchAlbum",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (responseData) {
            debugger;
            function writeTable() {
                var html = ''
                for (var i = 0; i < responseData; i++)
                    html += '<tr>';
                for (var j = 0; j < totalCells; j++) {
                    html += '<td>' + array[count] + '</td>';
                    count++;
                }
                html += '</tr>';
            }
            
            $('#body').append(html);
            
            count = 0;
            
        },
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   })
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

table#artistName tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: aquamarine
}

table#artistName tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: aquamarine
}

table#artistName th {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
   <p> Enter Artist Name:</p>
   <input id="artistName" type="text" />
   <button id="seachButton" onclick="searchClicked()">seach</button>
 </div>


<table id="ALbumInfo">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Album Name </th>
      <th>Release Date</th>
      <th>Popularity</th>
      <th>Number of Tracks</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I Really want to understand whats going wrong here.

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: So I am not seeing where you are trying to actually put the data into the table. Do have any code that actually attempts to do that or am I just missing it?

Comment: I've tried multiple ways, this is the one I am currently trying but I am getting absolutely no response.

Comment: Take a moment and read How to [Javascript Debugging line by line using Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638059/javascript-debugging-line-by-line-using-google-chrome).  The actual problem is very basic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're gettting the data you need back from that post request, I believe that the issue might be with:

```
$('#body').append(html);
```

That selector looks for an element with an id='body', which you do not have in your html. Instead, try using:

```
$('tbody').append(html);
```

Or put that id on your tbody html tag:

```
<tbody id='body'></tbody>
```

Then your script will append to that control.

Moving forwards try checking the developer's console to see errors your code is throwing. I would imagine you are getting an error with your code as is (CTRL-SHIFT-I or right click and choose inspect, depending on your web browser).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to flow this out with sample records, you'll notice that the variable `html` will have a value similar to this: `<tr><tr><tr><tr></tr>`--depending on how many records were returned from your AJAX request.

This, of course, assumes that the runtime doesn't crash due to `totalCells` being undefined. (As well as `array` and `count`.)

There are much better approaches to your problem, too. I would recommend:

```
    var table = $('<table><tbody></tbody></table>');
    var tbody = table.children('tbody');

    for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr></tr>');

        for (c = 0; c < totalCells; c++) {
            tr.append($('<td></td>').html(array[c]));
        }

        tbody.append(tr);
    }

    $('body').append(table);
```