# why I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sequence' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to track and handle the progress of the user through my web app slides, everything seems to work fine till I reach the **9th** execution of the function. at that point I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sequence' of undefined

Unfortunately, I don't know how to debug the code or realize **what causes the error** and I need a hand to fix it.

It seems that this for loop causes the error but why?

```
 // Fill planedSlides array
 for(let a = 1; a < current_slide; a++){    
        if(slides[a - 1].sequence == nextSequence && slides[a - 1].plan == true){
           console.log('a: ' + a)
           planedSlides.push(a);
        }
 }
```

```js
// Global Variables initiate at course start and modified throught the slides
// sequence A =>> serie 1 ----  serie 1 ---- serie 3 ----  serie 4

var slides = [
  
{ id: 1, difficulty: 2, performance: 20, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 0 },
{ id: 2, difficulty: 4, performance: 30, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: true, planned: 0 },
{ id: 3, difficulty: 4, performance: 40, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 0 },
{ id: 4, difficulty: 4, performance: 20, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: true, planned: 0 },
{ id: 5, difficulty: 4, performance: 50, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: true, planned: 0 },
{ id: 6, difficulty: 2, performance: 20, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 0 },
{ id: 7, difficulty: 4, performance: 30, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: true, planned: 0 },
{ id: 8, difficulty: 4, performance: 40, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 0 },
{ id: 9, difficulty: 4, performance: 20, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 0 },  

];

var current_slide; // assigned at each slide start
let lastViewedSlide;
let lastSlide = slides.length; // last slide of the course 
let courseEnded = false;

// Test Assignments 
current_slide = 1;


// Global Variable of progress()
let queue = []; 

// At each end of slide we just initiate the progress function.. 
function progress(e){
  
  // Check if we are in intro or outro 
  if(e){
    
     switch(e){
        // Intro slides with negative numbers incrementing.. slide 0 is the first slide..
        case -1:
        goToSlide(-1);
        break;    
         
        case -2:
        goToSlide(-2);
        break;
         
        case -3:
        goToSlide(-3);
        break; 
         
        // Outro slides with positive number beyond 100.. 
        case 101:
        goToSlide(101);
        break;    
         
        case 102:
        goToSlide(102);
        break;
         
        case 103:
        goToSlide(103);
        break;  
         
        // last intro slide executes progress like this: progress(1);
        case 1:      
        // Go to first slide and generate queue
        const firstSequence = slides[0].sequence;
        let iterate = 0;
         
        while(slides[iterate].sequence == firstSequence){
        iterate++
        queue.push(iterate);
        } 
         
        goToSlide(1); 
         
        break;  
            
            
     };
    
     return; 
    // return the whole progress function if we are in intro or outros..  
  }
  
  // Check if we have reached last course slide
  if(current_slide == lastSlide){
     courseEnded = true; // it'll remain true 
  };
  
  if(courseEnded === true){
     progressCourseEnded();
     return;
  };
  
  // initiate progress here
  queue.shift(); // Remove this slide from queue
  
  if(queue.length !== 0){
     goToSlide(queue[0]); // if the queue is NOT empty go to the first element of queue
  } else {
    // If the queue is empty fill it..
    fillQueue();
    
    // Then view the queue slide by slide
    goToSlide(queue[0]);
    
  }
  
    
 
  // fillQueue function to generate queue again
  function fillQueue(){

    let nextSequence = slides[current_slide].sequence;
    let iterate = current_slide;
    let planedSlides = [];
    let newSlides = [];
    
    // Fill planedSlides array
    for(let a = 1; a < current_slide; a++){    
        if(slides[a - 1].sequence == nextSequence && slides[a - 1].plan == true){
           console.log('a: ' + a)
           planedSlides.push(a);
        }
    }

    // Fill newSlides array
    while(slides[iterate].sequence == nextSequence){
    iterate++
    newSlides.push(iterate)
    }
    
    // Finally fill queue
    queue = planedSlides.concat(newSlides);

};
    
  
  
  
}

// goToSlide function test
function goToSlide(slide){
   console.log(slide);
   current_slide = slide;
   //let player = GetPlayer();
   //player.SetVar("goToSlide",slide);

};




// Tests
setTimeout(() => progress(1), 2000); // at slide intro

setTimeout(() => progress(), 4000); // executed at end of slide 1

setTimeout(() => progress(), 6000); // executed at end of slide 2

setTimeout(() => progress(), 8000); // executed at end of slide 3

setTimeout(() => progress(), 10000); // executed at end of slide 4

setTimeout(() => progress(), 12000); // executed at end of slide 5

setTimeout(() => progress(), 14000); // executed at end of slide 2

setTimeout(() => progress(), 16000); // executed at end of slide 6

setTimeout(() => progress(), 18000); // executed at end of slide 7 .. This throws the error
```

Comment: "I can't debug the code" Why not? Pretty much every desktop browser has a debugger built into it, and pretty much every mobile browser can be remotely debugged...

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey I don't understand what you say...

Comment: I don't understand why you can't debug the code.

Comment: So every human being started programming is able to solve all the issues in his code on his own?

Comment: Certainly not! Perhaps there's a language barrier here; when someone says they "can't" do something in English, that typically means there is something preventing them from doing it, not that they lack the skills. When one lacks the skills, one would say, "I don't know how to debug the code". There are plenty of tutorials online where you can learn to debug the code, and indeed [there is a question about doing so here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10638059/215552).

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey thanks for the link.. and by the way... I Love English... (Question has been edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, iterate in the following while loop is going out of bounds as iterate starts from slides array index 1:

```
// Fill newSlides array
while(slides[iterate].sequence == nextSequence){
   iterate++;
   newSlides.push(iterate);
}
```

I would have a console.log statement before and inside while statement.

Modify while loop

```
while(iterate < slides.length && slides[iterate].sequence == nextSequence){
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I was using Codepen and it showed me the for loop is the issue! chrome debugger shows the while loop!