# JavaScript Function returns twice but is only called once

Tags: javascript

I tried to figure out the problem but this code logs twice.  It logs John before the delay and "Robert" after the delay.

```js
let myName = 'John';
delayer();
myName = 'Robert';
function delayer() {
    console.log(myName);
    setTimeout(() => console.log(myName), 1500)
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you think `setTimeout` does?

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638059/javascript-debugging-line-by-line-using-google-chrome

Comment: What do you mean by “log out an assignment”? What else do you expect to happen? Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)?

Comment: `setTimeout(() => console.log(myName), 1500)` does not store the value at that moment in time. When it executes it reads the variable. Since you changed it before it executes, you have the updated value.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I was asking about why two different results would be returned even though the variable has one value which is either the first assigned value or the second assigned value

Comment: @epascarello thank you so much, you made it much clearer for me

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`() => console.log(myName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is the same as [`function() { return console.log(myName); }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).<sup>[1]</sup>

The resulting function reference is passed to `setTimeout` which arranges to call it after the specified delay. `setTimeout` doesn't wait for the delay to occur before returning. It returns immediately. So `myName` has been changed by the time the anonymous function has been called.

---

1. There are differences between the two approaches as itemized in the first link, but they don't come into play here.