# Having some difficulties in understanding Callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

First question is: What are callback functions?

Second question: How this code works and how it gets executed in JavaScript behind the scene?

The code:

```
// callback functions
const perOne = (friend, callfrnd) => {
  console.log(`I am busy right now. I am talking to ${friend}`);
  callfrnd();
};

const perTwo = () => {
  console.log(`Ok i will callback u later.`);
};

perOne("Kartik", perTwo);
```

Comment: A [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action. Usually used when asynchronous calls are completed.

Comment: Thank u so much but pls also tell me how that code just work and gets executed ?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code line by line to see how it works. [Instructions for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638059/javascript-debugging-line-by-line-using-google-chrome).

Comment: Ok let me do it

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Stack Overflow is not a forum or a mentoring site. It is a question-and-answer site. Single question, multiple answers, no chitchat.

Comment: Ok sure i will be concerned about it from the next time

Comment: `perOne` is called first with a string (`"Kartik"`) and function `perTwo` passed as arguments. Not all languages allow functions _themselves_ to be passed as arguments, but JS does. Inside `perOne`, parameter `callfrnd` now contains a reference to function `perTwo`; so inside `perOne` a string (`"I am busy right now..."`) is printed to the console, and then `callfrnd` (which is a reference to `perTwo`) is invoked (which prints `"Ok i will callback..."`).

Comment: Ok thank u so much ben aston its mean alot to me