# javascript line by line debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging

This might sound crazy but is there a debugger out there which automatically breaks on the first line of executed code ?

Sample : suppose I have debug mode on and I click on a button. Now the intelligent debugger should automatically set the breakpoint on the first line inside the .click({}) function.

This way it is very easy to see the starting point and very easy to backtrack.

There must surely be something.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338193/using-chrome-how-to-find-whos-binded-to-an-event/7338319#7338319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome with CTRL+SHIFT+J. ;) You can put breakpoints there. I think it also works under FF. Also new versions of IE have JavaScript debuggers (don't remember the shortcut though).

F12 in most browser opens the debugger.
Chrome, Safari, IE have this by default, and for FF there is the Firebug add on.

Comment: In IE 8 and 9 you can get to the developer tools by hitting F12 or Tools -> Developer Tools. The Javascript debugger is decent and allows for breakpoints.

Comment: Then how do you go line by line?

Answer (score 9):

Most debuggers in the browser allow you to insert the keyword

```
debugger;
```

into your code which will cause a break to occur at that point in the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can debug from visual studio, select debug from the menu --> Attach to process and then select the interter explorer process. But You should enable the script debuging in Internet Explorer first.