# chrome debugging, break on click event, execution should break when my js files are running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, code-inspection

I know how to break execution when I click on any element in the DOM for instance (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879969/1507546), by checking click event in the Mouse section of the source tab of the code inspector.

But What I don't know is how to skip all js files that are not mine and stop exection only when one of my js files is executed.