# Can I detect which javascipt functions do I trigger by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, function, events, find, detect

Is there any browser extension or any other way to detect which javascript functions do I trigger by pressing a button or a link? I know the basics of JS but I need to find which function is called by one event, but I cannot find it in the .js file, because the guy who wrote it was a total madman and named every variable with a single letter, so I want to find the specific part, instead of going through the whole file.

Comment: "total madman" -- are you sure you are not looking at a minified/uglified version of the code?

Comment: Also, use Event Listener Breakpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877190/chrome-debugging-break-on-next-click-event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use chrome dev tool and a breakpoint directly from that element.

Chrome Dev Tool:

[image]

hope it will help.

Comment: I meant, how to use it and where do I find it?

Comment: Hi! I edited my answer and include a screenshot image:

-You need to right click on the button with your mouse and click inspect
-Once chrome devtool open try to do whats on the image screenshoot

Then try to click everything that has red line or red box;