# Find who fired/triggered the event (Origin of triggered event)

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to know if there is a way to find from where a event was triggered, i have a form which makes use of multiple JavaScript libraries and in particular case a submit is triggered which is not desired. i want to find the origin of that event. Is there a way to add a listener which records the origin of the event when a specific type of event is triggered.

Something like this or may be something else:

```
el.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(e.getOrigin)
});
```

**Edit:**

just To make it clear, i know what **e.target** is, and no this is not what i am looking for

e.target gives the element on which that event was triggered, what i am looking for is - if the event was triggered from a function i want to know which function triggered it.

Comment: `event.target` (or `e.target` for your code) gives the element that triggered the event, is that what you want?  What do you mean by "origin"?

Comment: No, e.target gives the element on which that event was triggered, what i am looking for is - if the event was triggered from a function i want to know which function triggered it.

Comment: @AmitPandey What do you mean by *the event was triggered from a function*? How can a function trigger an event?

Comment: i have some libraries, which add manual event triggers to my elements, something like  element.dispatchEvent('click') or trigger() in jQuery . i want to find that if a click event was triggered it was which function or which piece of code, like from function x or function y.

Answer (score 3):

That's not something you are going to find in the language. If you are just trying to debug a particular situation, you might consider using <del>jQuery audit</del> *(this is no longer available in the chrome web store, but if you* really *want, you can get it from the [repo](https://github.com/zertosh/jquery-audit/issues/11#issuecomment-877935967))*, or set an [event listener breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879969/6789816) in the Sources tab of your Dev-tools.

Programatically, there is nothing you can do, unless you modify the existing libraries.

Comment: I will try this Jquery audit, thanks. Breakpoints are not useful for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(e.getOrigin)` replace, `e.getOrigin` with `e.target`

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the correct structure, but instead of `e.getOrigin` you need to use `e.target`. From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

> The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched

In your example, with a `click` event, this will return the element that was clicked by the user. Hopefully this is the behaviour you were expecting?