# Find out what method is fired when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a third-party plugin (igGrid) table on my page. I want to know what method is called when a specific button is clicked on this page. (The "Done" button when editing a row, if anyone is interested).

Essentially, how do I add a JavaScript break-point to a button? I'm using Chrome, and need to use Chrome.

EDIT:
I know what Chrome Dev Tools are, there is just nowhere to add a breakpoint to.

Comment: This is already covered in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338193/using-chrome-how-to-find-whos-binded-to-an-event

Comment: Thank you, this is as close as i'm going to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTRL+SHIFT+J`  to open up the dev console in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome console , CTRL+SHIFT+J and use the `console.log()` to debug

Comment: Damn , forget that in english this is called SHIFT