# How to find JS function name?

Tags: javascript

I have implemented on a website a picture gallery that does not allow (it seems) the auto sliding. So at the moment I have to push on a button to see the next picture. My purpose is to catch the function that allows to move to the next picture and to set a timeout to go to the next picture automatically.

How can I get the JS function name using Google Chrome developer tools?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

This is the Gallery script: http://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/
I would like to implement auto sliding on it

Comment: the function may not have a name...

Comment: Kind of a broad question... Have you tried looking at the element? At the JS code on the page?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Consider triggering fake click events, as if the user was pressing the button themselves.

Comment: @lorenzo83, you may possibly try debugging in the web browser console, press F12 and go to `script` tab, keep an eye on the method call stack

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338193/using-chrome-how-to-find-whos-binded-to-an-event

Comment: on www.annalilollo.it I see it sliding..

Comment: The auto sliding it's uncontrollable: if you push the cirlces while is sliding the timeout will change or the sliding can stop

Answer (score 1):

source for code proposal from: https://github.com/codrops/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/issues/4

```
(function() {
    function autoSliding(timeout) {
        var self = this;
        clearTimeout(self.timeOut);
        self.timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            self._navigate('next');
        }, timeout);
    }

    new Photostack( document.getElementById( 'photostack-1' ), {
        afterShowPhoto: function(context) {
            autoSliding.call(context, 3000)
        },
        afterNavigate: function(context) {
            autoSliding.call(context, 3000)
        }
    });

    new Photostack( document.getElementById( 'photostack-2' ), {
        afterShowPhoto: function(context) {
            autoSliding.call(context, 3000)
        },
        afterNavigate: function(context) {
            autoSliding.call(context, 3000)
        }
    });
}())
```

Comment: please, provide proof on jsfiddle - as I have tested it on Photostack

Comment: Strange – the same version but code is different from https://github.com/codrops/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery

Comment: I've changed the script and it works (I have used only a part of the code to avoid auto start!). Anyway the auto sliding it's uncontrollable: if you push the cirlces while is sliding the timeout will change.

Ideas?

Comment: I've edited code to make autosliding more predictable. I also added IFEE to avoid global scope polluting with helper variable and method

Comment: I can't make it work...I've tried with 2 galleries, if you start both and then you push randomly on the circles galleries stop.

Comment: One more edition and proof of concept: http://safjanowski.pl/stackoverflow/scattered/

Comment: It is not working, after pushing circles it stops (also on your proof)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
$('.navigate-next').click();
```

Or for auto scroll

```
setInterval(function(){$('.navigate-next').click();},1000);
```

Change 1000 for whatever you wish

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to use jquery in your code, then, you can use `$._data()` method.

syntax is `$._data($("selector of the element")[0], "events")`

This will return an `Object` of all events bounded to that element. Then get the `click` event and call the `handler` attribute of the `click` event.

Comment: No, this'll only return the events that _were bound with jQuery_.  If the slider used some other API then `$._data()` will be useless.

Comment: Yes if they use other libraries this will be useless, thats why i mentioned that "if you are allowed to use jquery in your code"

Comment: If he can use jQuery he'd be far better off with `$('#button').trigger('click')` than futzing about with the internals of jQuery's list of bound event handlers, and the above `.trigger` call would work even if the slider used some other API.