# How to know which function(s) is(are) associated to an event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

There is any way to know which function(s) is(are) associated to an event (for example click event of a div)?

Notes:

1. I'm using Chrome dev tool
2. There is no need the solution uses javascript.

Comment: [Using Chrome, how to find who's binded to an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338319) ?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much, I search a lot and I didn't find anything, even when i was making this question (maybe I used wrong search's queries).