# How can I see if an anonymous .js function has been attached to onclick event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to make sure that the function below gets "attached" to the appropriate Event.
The function does execute, but I can't see it in the Chrome > Global Listeners. (I assume it would be under Mouse, Click event)

```
/* expander control */
$().ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.js-expander', function(e){
    var e =  e || event, 
        $el = $(this), 
        $content;

    e.preventDefault();

    $content = $el.parent().next('.js-expander-content')
    if ($content.length == 0)
      $content = $el.parent().parent().next('.js-expander-content')
      if ($content.length == 0)
        $content = $el.siblings('.js-expander-content');

    $content.slideToggle(150);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of your `.on` method call is “a selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event.”

This means that you won't find your `click` event attached to the document (global event); instead, it will be attached to each one of elements matching the selector (".js-expander").

You may want to examine the event handlers attached to each one of these elements, if there's any such element in the first place (try: `console.log($(".js-expander").length);` )

Comment: Add a link to this answer and I'll mark you response the Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236337/4906

Comment: Dumb question: where do I type the console.log command? (I tried in the console > prompt, but got a syntaxerror : unexpected token.