# Jquery .change() to view currently assigned method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way I can view the current method assigned to a selects change event. 
I have tried.

```
$('#select').change()
```

but that just returns me the change event. I don't really need to do this but would be very handy for debugging. Save me hunting through the code to find the method, this way I can simply search the text in the method and find the method quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#select').data('events').change;
```

This will contain an array of objects, one per event handler.

---

If you're sure there's only one change event handler, you can access the function directly:

```
var theFunction = $('#select').data('events').change[0].handler;
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/7UD3e/

Comment: Just for any lurkers, that's not in the documented jQuery API. No problem if you're just debugging, but if you use it for production it's likely to break in 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

A slight alteration to Joseph's answer will make the actual code for the function be output:

```
var clickEvents = $('#select').data("events").change;
$.each(clickEvents, function(key, handlerObj) {
    console.log(handlerObj.handler) // prints actual function code, does not run function
})
```

*Source: [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug (or similar tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)*

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7UD3e/2/