# View listener body in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools, event-listener

In chrome developer tools you're able to inspect the listeners attached to an element.

[image]

The listenerBody is clipped because the inspector isn't big enough to show it in it's entirety. How do you view the entire listenerBody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can jump into the method using listener breakpoints. See [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer#answer-10213800) for details.