# Does Google Chrome MonitorEvent support custom events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, events

Simple question. I would like to monitor every time a custom event ('connect") is fired.

As per [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer) and http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents, I can use MonitorEvent to monitor events in chrome. However, I am not sure if this supports custom events?

For example, I have a custom event bound by jQuery using `$(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {//code here;});`

but if I type `monitorEvents($0, 'connect') into the console`

I don't see any monitored events, even though the event is most definitely triggered in my code.

Thanks!

C

Answer (score 0):

monitorEvents isn't part of the jQuery library so it won't catch the bespoke events... it is part of the console object and therefore only 'sees' proper browser events.
I recommend you look up how custom jQuery events work and create your own logger, at least with jQuery it's easy, just set a event listener on the document.