# How can I inspect a rollover status?

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I would like to inspect the rollover status of a drop-down menu.
I tried to do that with the Chrome inspector and its *Toggle Element State* feature as you can see here:

[image: :hover state toggled on within the Chrome DevTools]

Though this way doesn't work for me.

I would like to inspect the submenu of this site: http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/strata/

So I can add some extra CSS rules while the menu is still open.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick glance, you can add `class = "drop_down_start"` to the nested `div` for the specific menu header to want to investigate. As long as that class is present, the sub-menu will be visible/displayed.

> Simply right click the element in the inspector **->** Edit as HTML **->** add the class `drop_down_start`

before:

```
<div class="second bellow_header" style="height: 0px; top: 85px;"><div class="inner"><ul>
```

after:

```
<div class="second bellow_header drop_down_start" style="height: 0px; top: 85px;"><div class="inner"><ul>
```

**NOTE:**

The menu will persistently try to close. So, if needed, [disable javascript](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0).

Comment: thanks @travis, works well.
i am thinking, is this the only method to do this?

Comment: @mattia Actually there is. Check out this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10213800/4279440). This allows you to view events fired on an element in Chrome Web Developer? This event to catch in this case would be the `mouseout....so Sources > Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > mouseout` It will in essence freeze the page on `mouseout` events aka when you attempt to remove your mouse from the nav item. Then you can browse at the element styles as you please.