# Alert on clicking minimize, close, restore down and new tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to give alert to user when they try to navigate away from the webpage, by performing events mentioned in the title.

1. Do I need to develop an chrome extension for that?

Comment: Check this question [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome Web Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer)

Comment: No, I guess what you need is to implement some javascipt that listens to Try checking the available events here. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp