# How do I find all scroll listeners on my document/window object?

Tags: javascript

I have put my website through a performance analysis tool, and it has come back saying that there are too many scroll listeners on the document/window object.

Is there a way of finding all my scroll listeners for my document/window object?

Something maybe along the lines of :

```
window.scroll.listeners
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can use:

```
//Change window, for any other element you want to check. IE: document
$._data(window, "events");
```

You can check **all jquery events** attached to an element, so if someone did:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){ console.log("scroll"); });
```

You'll see something like this:

[image]

Using plain javascript, you can "intercept" the `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` to check all events listeners attached to window, or any element for that matter:

```
(function(){
    function interceptListener(type, element){
        if(typeof element[type] == "function"){
            element[type] = (function(){
                var original = this[type];
                this.allListeners = this.allListeners || {};
                return function() {
                    this.allListeners[arguments[0]] = arguments[0] in this.allListeners ? this.allListeners[arguments[0]] + 1 : 1;

                    return original.apply(this, arguments);
                }

            }.bind(element))();
        }
    }

    interceptListener("attachEvent", window);
    interceptListener("addEventListener", window);
})();
```

Place this snippet **before** any other scripts.

If you want to check if `window.onscroll` was set, you can just test on window load if any other script set it:

```
if(typeof window.onscroll == "function")
    console.log("onscroll function");
```

Or you can watch the property with: [object watch polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583)

```
window.watch("onscroll", function(){
    if(typeof this.onscroll == "function")
        this.allListeners["onscroll"] = this.allListeners["onscroll"] + 1 : 1;
});
```

Then you can check how many listeners are attached to window with:

```
console.log(window.allListeners);
```

**NOTE:** as @JuanMendes pointed out: `Be aware that this is an internal data structure that is undocumented and should not be modified` and should only be used for debugging.

Comment: This is only for jQuery listeners, events could have been set directly without jQuery

Comment: Yes I know, I said that: "You can check all jquery events attached to an element"

Comment: @OliverWatkins check my edited answer to intercept an event using vanilla js.

Comment: I know you know, I'm just making sure others know that this doesn't fully answer the question. You should also explain that this method is for debugging only.  `but be aware that this is an internal data structure that is undocumented and should not be modified` http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/

Comment: I know I'm being extra picky, but your vanilla JS function also doesn't account for `window.resize = function` and `window.attachEvent()`

Comment: I know,  but I like giving the tools to the OP so he can make that by himself, using my snippet,  he can easily make that for himself, and learn in the way :), and anyhow window.resize wasn't part of the question, he wanted only scroll listeners.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I meant `window.onscroll`. The problem with half an answer is that others come to StackOverflow expecting an answer marked as accepted to be correct. We're always trying to answer the question and help all other users, not just the one asking the question.

Comment: @JuanMendes I'll edit the answer, with a full one, as soon as I get to my computer ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your input, and now please check my answer, and let me know if you like it now :)

Comment: Thanks for putting up with my "suggestions" :)

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to find them, you can use chrome dev tools.

Copied from answer below:

> You can right click on the target element -> select "inspect element" Scroll down on the right side of the dev frame, at the bottom is 'event listeners'. Expand the tree to see what events are attached to the element. Not sure if this works for events that are handled through bubbling (I'm guessing not)

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Listeners Tab]

See [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer)

Also, you can programmatically do it in Chrome

```
getEventListeners(window)
```

See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544813/227299 and https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject