# How do I see Backbone specific event listeners in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools, event-listener

I looked at previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-web-developer) and went through the Event Listeners Tab and then clicked the Framework Listeners checkbox but it still doesn't show Backbone listeners.

Comment: Did you go to Event Listeners Breakpoints? In there, you can find all types of events you can click on all of them and run the debugger and see them trigger.

Comment: @DiegoGallegos it has all the events that can happen, but I'm looking for Backbone specific events like change events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome Dev Tools, you can use the `Event Listener Breakpoints` panel under Sources to break on certain events, for example `click`:

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints]

You can then step through the code and follow the Call Stack to determine where problems may exist. If you find yourself stepping into external library code, you can right click on it to blackbox it:

[image: Blackboxing code]

Alternatively, there is a good blog post below that shows a technique of writing out stack traces and overriding the Backbone `trigger` function to inject a trace function before returning the result of the original Backbone`trigger` function: http://lifeinvistaprint.com/techblog/debugging-backbone-chrome/

I documented this kind of technique for general debugging on my blog recently:
https://gideonpyzer.com/blog/debugging-javascript-by-redefining-functions/

There is also a [Backbone Debugger Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd?hl=en), which may be of use to you.