# Chrome Inspection Tool: debugging disappearing popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When I try to click on the "Inspect this" field on a popup which appears only onMouseHover event it can become very annoying.

https://youtu.be/4lPcO00MUYk

And since it's frequent to attach a javascript behavior to any DOM element event through selectors I can't imagine how to debug this web pages.

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can either force a style, in the inspect elements>style on the top right you have a `:hov` you can click on to activate hovered state and such. You can also force a style for the element by typing in the styles, or add a class with the `.cls` to force the visibility

Comment: @Kaddath: thanks, I tried but it's not associated with the style.. it shows an extra div onmouse over, but I don't know where this div code is..

Comment: mmh i see, if this is triggered by javascript, if you find the element on which the listener is, you can try to type in the console (sorry, this is jquery version, js vanilla is quite longer): `$('#idOfElement').trigger('mouseover');` (it might be necessary to adapt the event name, depending on your case)

Comment: @Kaddath: nothing works... this is the page: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotecnologia I tried to add an id but the popup doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a question which may help with my problem, but also @Kaddath solution is very interesting.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15923770/196210