# Override and cancel all jquery/javascript events on a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

I have a drupal site in development and have installed a module (we_megamenu) which as standard created a hamburger menu (when below 991px) which when clicked opens an off canvas menu.

Now the design requirement is that the menu not be off canvas so I need to override/cancel the click and/or touch event(s) and then override the CSS to make it a menu which appear under the site header.

I can't modify the modules JS directly as it is a contributed codebase, so I need to somehow ensure the event simply doesn't fire and then uses mine instead.

I've managed to stop the scripts in the debugger using Chromes dev tools as explained here: [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-devtools)

Problem is the code running is buried in the js.min source and I cannot find the module's calling function, not that its any use to me as I cannot modify their code.

Is there a way to remove all functions from a given element? Cancelling all events would be easier that over riding if possible.

Regards and thanks
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular jQuery you can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove event listeners and then attach your own, but since you are using drupal, you might want to look into their native mechanisms to do that: [Drupal behaviours](https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/javascript/behaviors.html).

If it helps, you can find the raw js for the module [here](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/we_megamenu/tree/assets/js).

Comment: Thanks msg, appreciated.