# View events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools always lead to zone.js file, How i find the real code?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a feature in chrome dev tools(or any extension) by which I can view the real event listeners that are used on a certain page/app and not the zone.js file ?

[How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-devtools) work only for Vanilla JS Apps, how to acheive that with Angular Apps ?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

[Angular DevTools](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-devtools-2d59ff4cf62f) may be come in handy for your purpose.

**Angular DevTools supports applications built with Angular v9 and above with Ivy enabled.*

With help of if you may visualize your angular app structure. Then you select the component you want to listen and this component appears "Sources" tab.

[image: angular-devtools open source of component button]