# How to know which handler get fired in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom-events

Is there anyway I can figure out perhaps using firebug, when I click on a element the name(s)/body(s) of a function which get called.

> for an example I want to know what are the Javascript functions that got
> triggered when I press tweet button.

Please note that I am not talking about `eventLog`, breakpoints, or anything that requires to modify the source code.

I found out that [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) is an amazing tool which can help to visualize all the events attached with different elements.

Comment: You could set a break point on the different functions in firebug/inspector and step through them.

Comment: The answer seems to be here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: thanks Stasik  [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) is the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Firebug, but in Webkit Inspector, under the Scripts tab, under Breakpoints, then Event Listener Breakpoints, you can select different types of events in a hierarchical structure (Keyboard, Mouse, etc, and under those, each individual event).

When the event is triggered, the debugger will break.