# Enable/Disable button click handlers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, let's say that I have a button and I would like to enable/disable its click handlers.

I would like to create functions like these:

```
var bar = [];
function storeHandlers(buttonID) {
    //I would like to store the click handlers in bar[buttonID]
}

function preventHandlers(buttonID) {
    storeHandlers(buttonID);
    //I would like to disable all the click handlers for button
}

function loadHandlers(buttonID) {
    //I would like to enable all the handlers loaded from bar[buttonID]
}
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can namespace your event handlers and enable/disable groups of handlers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
function preventClick(buttonID) {
    $('#'+buttonID).data('events').saved_click = $('#'+buttonID).data('events').click;
    $('#'+buttonID).data('events').click = null;
}

function allowClick(buttonID) {
    $('#'+buttonID).data('events').click = $('#'+buttonID).data('events').saved_click;
}
```

That's it!

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cec6z/9/

Comment: This looks like a nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't store/retrieve the event handlers from just the ID of the elements, you have store those manually while creating handlers. But you can `on/off` handlers like following

```
function preventHandlers(buttonID) {
    $('#'+buttonID).off('click',bar[buttonID]);
}

function loadHandlers(buttonID) {
   $('#'+buttonID).on('click',bar[buttonID]);
}
```

And you can store them like

```
bar[buttonID] = function(event){

};
```

**UPDATE:**

Though the answers here at [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug (or similar tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool) and here [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106) and others are saying that `.date('events')` returns all event handlers, i could not get it to work.

I have set up an example with the way stated above. Chek the following link

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/cec6z/)

Comment: +1 If I can disable them and enable them without storing them that's very nice, I didn't even dare to hope this is possible.

Comment: @LajosArpad, I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I don't think you can retrieve all event callbacks from a jquery object such like

```
var handlers = $('#buttonId').unbind('click')
```