# Is it possible to find all JavaScript event listeners of a element using the browser "inspect element"?

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom-events, web-inspector

I have too many Javascript files associated with my web page and I would like to know all the events that an element is associated to. It's for debugging purpose.

For example, I want to know which events are associated with a span with a class `class-span` and id `id-span`

```
<span id = "id-span" class="class-span">Something</span>
```

Is it possible to use the developer tool of a web browser to find this information?  If yes, how?

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863400/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-event-handlers-of-an-element-with-javascript

Comment: Check out the following SO question [How to use getEventListeners in Chrome Dev Tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544306/how-to-use-geteventlisteners-in-chrome-dev-tool)