# How to lookup/debug a list of all jQuery events bindings if you don't know the id or class of the elements

Tags: javascript, click, jquery

I added jQuery click events dynamically using the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)-function:

```
$("#elementId").click(function() {
    debugger;
    //Some code
});
```

I realize that you can find the events by using the [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('#elementId').data("events");
```

But what if you want to find them, if any, dynamically? E.g.

```
<div id="containerWithComplexStructure">
    //Some elements with .click events may be in here
</div>
```

How do you then find them if you **don't know their id or class**?

And can you access them through the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) frame (or similar tools), being able to browse their variables etc.?

Similar to this (click the image to enlarge):

[Chrome Developer Tools view, stopped at a breakpoint http://imageshack.us/a/img138/1209/findclickfunction.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img138/1209/findclickfunction.png)

> For a single known element see: [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug (or similar tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, `console.log( jQuery('#elementId').data('events') );` in your code;

or just `jQuery('#elementId').data('events');` in the console.

To view events from all elements:

```
var elements_with_events = 0;
$('*').each(function(i,e){

    if($(e).data('events')){
        console.log( $(e) );
        console.log( $(e).data('events') );
        elements_with_events++;
    }

});
console.log( elements_with_events + ' elements have events.' );
```

<s>... and wait for the crash.</s> Actually this works surprisingly fast.

You could add a class when attaching events also. Then you aren't searching for events per say but classes.

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify, I don't know the ID of the elements, I'll edit my post

Comment: While your new answer actually answers half my question, I realize jQuery's CSS selector is fine for the job, but what if you want to do it realtime (since console.log isn't) with breakpoints? I'm guessing I could temporarily store them in a variable, so I could access them through the debugger, but I'll have to try that

Comment: @AskeB. What *half* of the question did I miss?

Comment: "*And can you access them through e.g. the Chrome Developer Tools frame?*" which was a bad articulation for asking how to find them via breakpoints (in the debug/developer tools or similar) or similar more efficient *and* consistent ways than using `console.log`

Comment: `console.log` spits them out to the *Developer Tools frame*. Have you tried the code above with breakpoints. I personally have never used breakpoints so if that was actually in the OP I wouldn't have bothered. I hope my contribution helps answer the OP and maybe even the question in your head. :)

Comment: Yes it does. In Chrome's developer tools frame, you're able to do `console.log($(element).data('events'), "Event object");` And that prints out an object which can be [expanded/browsed realtime in their GUI](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). It would be more flexible to be able to do that with jQuery events as well, which is also something I wanted covered in this question. I guess my articulation skills didn't suffice this time around. Thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: An off-topic note: I stopped relying on `console.log` when I found out that the following two log calls printed two identical objects (and not a before and after version): `var div = $('#someBigDiv'); console.log(div, 'Div before emptying it'); $(div).empty(); console.log(div, 'Div after emptying it');`, and breakpoints seemed like a consistent choice when you want to check several things at a given time in the code and want to make sure it's what the variables and objects actually look like at the time.

Comment: Cool. Will have to look into it.