# jQuery won't get called from MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I use a [jQuery DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) in many places in my web app. It works fine everywhere exept in one place where the calendar just won't pop up. Here's the source code of the page (view in Chrome).

```
<script>
    $('#example9').datetimepicker({ timeFormat: 'h:mm', stepMinute: 5, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="example9" id="example9" value="2012-10-16 15:00" />
</div>
```

As you can see, I've reduced the code to the simplest and added an event listener. Nothing is triggered and nothing happens whenever I click the input.

Any clue?

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? Is jQuery included in this page?

Comment: If i'm looking at this correctly, every time you click in the input box, it pops up an alert, which effectively causes focus to not be set, so it would never pop up.

Comment: @Oded : No error in the JS console of FireBug. No query either

Comment: @MystereMan The pop up doesn't show up either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

1. jQuery and your plugin are loaded.
2. your script is run after the DOM is loaded (*or at least after the used element is rendered*). So move your `script` code after the `div` element, or use `$(document).ready(function(){/*your-code*/});`
3. the `id` is unique in the html or it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do it that way? Instead of calling the datepicker on each specific input based on ID, just create an HTML class that all datepicker inputs will have. Then in your _Layout, or other JavaScript file that always gets called, turn everything with that class into a DatePicker.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this

```
.data("events")
```

I do not see a **data-events** attribute for the textbox

Comment: You mean something like '<input type="text" ... data-events="events"/>'?

Comment: Yup... data-events="something here"

Comment: something-here should be either an array of objects or just an array according to your logic

Comment: var clickEvents = $('#example9').data("events").click;  makes no sense at all  ..

Comment: $('#example9').data("events")  return events .. It is a string here.. And you are trying to chain with click , which is not present for the string...

Comment: Here's my source (the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: That is if you already have events associated with the element