# Chrome and JS onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome

I wanted to test chrome to see if it can show me what method will be running for `onclick` registered event.

So I wanted to see which JS function execute shen people upvotes a  question :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mbce.jpg

[image]

But I couldn't found the actual code.

is it possible with chrome to find which JS executes when "onclick"?

## edit

I could use the console to do it with :

```
$.each($(".vote-up-off").data("events"), function(i, e) {  // this will work till jq 1.8
  console.log(this)
});
```

and  here  is  our friend:

[image]

But **hey** ! , I want chrome to do the work :-)

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome's JavaScript CPU profiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some workarounds available
U may try this bookmarklet concept
[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)

Add bookmarklet to you browser bookmarks(enable bookmarks bar show always) and click on bookmark while on the page u want to debug

PS: it is for Jquery

Answer (score 3):

One potential insight might be to enter this in your console and press return:

```
$('.vote a').data('events').click;
```

jQuery stores all of its events which are bound to an object [inside of the data() object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571087/427992); so if you want to view a particular event binding, this is your place to look. Console will return an object. Expand `handler` --> `<function scope>` --> `Closure` and you can now see all of the associated JavaScript around this click event.

Comment: Awesome, well done. Saves me having to upload a screenshot now!