# How can I figure out where Javascript is changing my focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on an ASP.Net project that has a large number of js files, most from third party sources. On a number of pages, the focus is being set to a control other than the one I'm setting it to in code-behind (Control.Focus()). How can I figure out how, why, and where the focus is being changed?

I have installed [FireFocus](http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firefocus/) for FireBug so I can see the focus being changed, but I cannot see the cause.

Comment: Duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: Try using jQuery to add a `focus` event handler to the element that is wrongly receiving focus. From there set a breakpoint and look at the call stack to figure out where the focus is being set from. I am not sure if FireBug shows the call stack (it should) but Chrome developer tools does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link provided by Moby's Stunt Double, I added the following code to the bottom of my page and every time the focus was changed, the call stack was dumped to my console so I could trace the source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#TabInformation").on("focus", function (event) {
        try { throw new Error("dummy"); } catch (e) { console.log(e.stack); }
    });
</script>
```