# Cross browser compatibility issue for showing and hiding div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have MVC app.

I have written below code in the JS in Create view.
Basically on the basis of selection on drop down I show and hide the div.
Now the problem is below code works perfectly in Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox. 
but now working in IE 8.

What should I do ?

```
$('#PaymentType').change(function(){            
            var ptype=document.getElementById("PaymentType").value;        
            if(ptype=="On Account")
            {
                $(".InvoiceDiv").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".InvoiceDiv").show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Check Orders Of <Link > tag for adding Css and Js Files

Comment: Can you test by FireBug and check it out?

Comment: How to test it ? means, when I change the item in combo box the div get hide, and its works in firefox...how to test in firebug the changed event ?

Comment: For Handling using this link 
:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool

Comment: The Eventbug extension has been released yesterday, see: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what real issue is but since you are using jQuery why don't you use it for your ptype, too? With this, cross-browser issue will be minimized (if not completely avoided).

```
$('#PaymentType').change(function(){            
    var ptype = $(this).val();        
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this helps... getElementById is not supported in IE 8. I am using the same. Which other property should I use ? If I wan to get value of other controls in same function ?

Comment: @user1650894 you mean calling other elements inside that function using jQuery? Take a look at jQuery selectors further here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

If your Js files has  full of references to a method called document.getelementbyid 
Or order of your Js files and Css files which you import to program with < Link / > Tag  ,
 Reorder them and test it in IE
i think  that the reason your code breaks right at the beginning of the function.

Comment: thanks Ali, but i am quite confused , can you explain me in simple manner, I am new to MVC and scripts...