# How do I determine what element received an event?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I just finished a pretty intense debugging session where my `cucumber` test code would work using `webkit` but wouldn't work using `selenium`. The problem was solved by being very specific about the exact DOM element that was clicked. I needed to specify clicking a deeply nested `<span>` element. This brought up a question for which I'm not sure how to answer:

**How do I know what element, initially, received an event?**

I've read a bit about event bubbling, so even if my element's event handler fires, it doesn't mean that it was the initial element to receive the event. I don't understand why Chrome was able to accept a click event that was propagated down to the correct element that fired off my handler, but Firefox didn't propagate the event down.

[This question on debugging events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool) doesn't quite capture my question, because in this case I didn't know what element to examine. I basically guessed correctly. I'd love a more methodical process to use to debug. Bonus points for helping me understand better the JS event bubbling/propagation model.

Answer (score 1):

It's `target` property of the event object.

```
domElement.addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
    console.log(e.target); 
});
```