# How to find the function executed on an event in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

I am using Firebug in Firefox. A button has various attributes like `id`, `name` and `class`. I am having a hard time to find out, which JavaScript function is getting exectued using Firebug.

Is there a quick way to get to know, which function gets executed when I click on an HTML element?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. As far as I understand what you want to know is how to get the event handlers for a specific element and this was [already asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/570960/432681).

Answer (score 1):

You could add some code like `console.log("In function 1");` to the functions to determine which are being called, if there aren't many functions. You can also check the `onclick=""` attribute on the HTML of the buttons or if the page uses jQuery the `$(".some-class").on('click', function(){})` functions.

I think you should know what functions you are supposed to be calling, unless you're doing some reverse engineering or trying to copy/emulate some code from another page.