# How to review jQuery function execution related to specific events using Firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, jquery-events

I cannot for the life of me, after reading all of the documentation and probably twenty different Stack posts on the topic, figure out how to very simply view a log of JavaScript/jQuery function execution on a particular page using Firebug.

For example, I am attempting to determine which events are tied to a particular event (link being clicked, resulting in odd/unexpected behavior). I've heard over and over again that Firebug is the tool to use for this, but after ripping out the last few hairs remaining on my head over the last several hours, I can't figure it out.

Can someone please dummy-proof this for me? I'm not profiling. I'm not trying to look at the resources. I just want to see what JavaScript or jQuery code is executed as it relates to a specific user event (in this case, any link being clicked).

Comment: in firefox when you inspect an element tied to some js event, it should show a little "EV" icon next to it; that's where events are shown. can you confirm you can see that icon? example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners

Comment: That's it right there! Thank you.

Comment: Firebug has an *Events* side panel for this. See the answer there for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27974239/432681