# How to find out event handlers are bound to an event type in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keyevent

Is there a way to list all eventhandlers which are bound to an event type?

Comment: I liked your question, I tried some searching and found out these two questions [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) , [How to debug JavaScript/jQuery event bindings with Firebug or similar tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)

You may get some help reading these posts.

Comment: __unclear what you're asking__

Comment: Its not about regular event binding on elements where I could get the events by $(".stuff")._data("events") - I'm about to check what events are bound to keys. Another way to ask this question is: "is there a way to list all eventhandlers which are bound to an event type"